# Why the sites dropdown in multi-site installation is different from the list of sites when seen full page?

Tags: multisite, configuration

I have a multi-site installation directory-based.

When seen here https://freshideas.top/wp-admin/network/sites.php I see 4 sites:

[image: in network: seen 4 sites]

Instead in the dropdown, I see only 2 sites:

[image: in menu: seen 2 sites]

In this other page https://freshideas.top/wp-admin/my-sites.php I see also only 2 sites:

[image: in sites page: seen 2 sites too]

## Question

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not listing the same thing.

- one is a list of sites in the multisite, aka all 4 sites
- the other is a list of sites that you have a role on, aka 2 sites

To see all 4 sites you need a role on all sites. Being a super admin lets you browser the admin area of sites without needing a role, as the super admin flag overrides any checks.